# How to delete same data on the date in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file like below.

```
In 'order.csv'

date   orderName    orderNumber      state
1/7      Tom            1         
1/7      Jeny           4 
1/7      Brown          2
1/7      Tom            3         
1/8      Sky            5
1/8      Blue           7
1/8      Red            6
1/8      Wine           8
1/9      Tom            9                  
1/9      Earth          11         
1/9      Earth          10
```

I want to get the result below through an algorithm.

```
In 'order.csv'

date   orderName    orderNumber      state
1/7      Tom            1          duplicated
1/7      Jeny           4 
1/7      Brown          2
1/7      Tom            3          duplicated
1/8      Sky            5
1/8      Blue           7
1/8      Red            6
1/8      Wine           8
1/9      Tom            9                  
1/9      Earth          11         duplicated 
1/9      Earth          10         duplicated
```

There is a Tom on 1/9 also. But since the date is different, it is not considered as duplicated. Only to duplicate is considered depends on each date. 

How can I make this algorithm by python?
Thank you so much.

Comment: do you want to delete both values or just the 2nd one? or you just want them marked a duplicated? The title of your question says delete. but the expected output shows something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for get all duplicates per columns specified in list and for set new column [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['state'] = np.where(df.duplicated(['date','orderName'], keep=False), 'duplicated', '')
print (df)
   date orderName  orderNumber       state
0   1/7       Tom            1  duplicated
1   1/7      Jeny            4            
2   1/7     Brown            2            
3   1/7       Tom            3  duplicated
4   1/8       Sky            5            
5   1/8      Blue            7            
6   1/8       Red            6            
7   1/8      Wine            8            
8   1/9       Tom            9            
9   1/9     Earth           11  duplicated
10  1/9     Earth           10  duplicated
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.duplicated(['date','orderName'], keep=False))
0      True
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10     True
dtype: bool
```

If need delete rows with all duplicated values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask by `~` - so it select all rows if not duplicates:

```
df1 = df[~df.duplicated(['date','orderName'], keep=False)]
```

---

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['date','orderName'], keep=False)
```

```
print (df1)
  date orderName  orderNumber  state
1  1/7      Jeny            4    NaN
2  1/7     Brown            2    NaN
4  1/8       Sky            5    NaN
5  1/8      Blue            7    NaN
6  1/8       Red            6    NaN
7  1/8      Wine            8    NaN
8  1/9       Tom            9    NaN
```

Comment: Wow almost identical answer. But much better than mine with all the details :) +1. and deleting mine